# Facing some attribute node issue

Tags: xslt

I am having the following code on my full length XSLT, and, its creates some errors during transformation.
The error is `XPTY0004: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of matches()`

```
<xsl:template match="par[@class='tablecaption']" exclude-result-prefixes="html">
<p class="caption1">
<xsl:variable name="n2" select="./text()|./*/text()"/>
<xsl:attribute name="id">
<xsl:if test="matches($n2, '(Table)\s(\d+|[A-Z])(\.)(\d+)')">
<xsl:variable name="y2" select="replace($n2, '(Table)\s(\d+|[A-Z])(\.)(\d+)', '$4')"/>Tab<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring($y2, 1, 2))"/></xsl:if>
</xsl:attribute>
<strong><xsl:apply-templates/></strong></p>
</xsl:template>
```

What is the wrong here? pls

Answer (score 0):

Change your variable `n2` to `./descendant::text()[1]`

```
<xsl:template match="par[@class='tablecaption']" exclude-result-prefixes="html">
<p class="caption1">
<xsl:variable name="n2" select="./descendant::text()[1]"/>
<xsl:attribute name="id">
<xsl:if test="matches($n2, '(Table)\s(\d+|[A-Z])(\.)(\d+)')">
<xsl:variable name="y2" select="replace($n2, '(Table)\s(\d+|[A-Z])(\.)(\d+)', '$4')"/>Tab<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring($y2, 1, 2))"/></xsl:if>
</xsl:attribute>
<strong><xsl:apply-templates/></strong></p>
</xsl:template>
```

with this input

```
<root>
    <par class="tablecaption"> Table A.1 <bold>text2</bold></par>
</root>
```

it gets:

```
<root>
    <p class="caption1" id="Tab1"><strong> Table A.1 <bold>text2</bold></strong></p>
</root>
```

Comment: Then, what is the solution here? Could you please let me know changes to do?

Comment: replace `<xsl:variable name="n2" select="./text()|./*/text()"/>` with `<xsl:variable name="n2" select="./descendant::text()"/>`

Comment: oops, that should be `<xsl:variable name="n2" select="./descendant::text()[1]"/>`